# Risks of applying aspects to assemblies using Postsharp

Tags: c#, postsharp

I want to apply aspects to 3rd party assemblies using postsharp for mainly logging the errors as described in this blog
http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/applying-aspects-to-3rd-party-assemblies-using-postsharp/.
This functionality is undocumented and not officially supported by postsharp. I am not sure about what kind of risks it may cause.
I know the risk will depend on my assemblies.
What would be the general risks I need to consider before following this approach?
Thanks

Comment: Starting with PostSharp 4.3 applying aspects to existing assemblies is officially supported. You can find more about this feature in the documentation: http://doc.postsharp.net/command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this unsupported feature of PostSharp you risk that it can be removed in a future version or changed without backward compatibility. Another important risk is that if you run into a problem, then you won't be able to get help from the official source.

Based on these risks you need to decide whether you want your project to depend on the feature.

If your main goal is logging the calls to referenced 3rd party assemblies, then it can also be implemented using another approach. You can apply the logging attribute in your own assembly and set the property [AttributeTargetAssemblies](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/P_PostSharp_Extensibility_MulticastAttribute_AttributeTargetAssemblies) to the name of the target 3rd party assembly.

```
[assembly:Log(AttributeTargetAssemblies="Some.Referenced.Assembly", AttributeTargetTypes="...", ...)]
```

With this approach PostSharp doesn't modify the target assembly, but instead modifies the calls made from your own assembly to the target assembly.

**UPDATE:**
Starting with PostSharp 4.3 applying aspects to existing assemblies is officially supported. You can find more about this feature in the documentation: http://doc.postsharp.net/command-line

Answer (score 0):

> "What would be the general risks I need to consider before following this approach?"

Another risk/annoyance to using PostSharp in general is that they update frequently.

An example...

- You have a solution with multiple projects
- You apply the current PS nuget package package to them
- Postsharp releases an update for VS and you install it
- You then have to include PostSharp into an existing or new project in the solution (a PostSharp wizard prompts this update)

What happens is that the new version of post sharp is applied to that project, and now you have some projects on version 12 and some on version 13 of postsharp. When you go to deploy, the application crashes because of version mismatch.

Comment: This issue has been addressed in version 4.1 of PostSharp VS extension. PostSharp now always tries to match the version already used in the solution when installing NuGet package. More info about 4.1 in the [announcement](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Announcing-PostSharp-41-RTM).